# Meteor: ensure a function doesnt throw an exception on remote data

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I am using Meteor and am pulling in a large amount of data from remote api calls. The calls are returning data objects that my function is expecting to have a certain structure and contain certain keys. However, sometimes the request or returned results could be buggy and in some situations the remote data will return two objects that have different keys for the same value. ie: {name: tyler}, {firstName: joe}. So far, I have just been "patching" these differences or buggy returns as they come but I was wondering if there was a better method to ensure that if an object with a strange key is returned or a buggy request of a structure i'm not checking for is that I can catch all of these possibilities and ensure that the correct value is mapped to the key name ive decided for the app's data and that a default value is placed if all are missed. ie: with {name: tyler}, {firstName: joe}, {userName: alex}, if i was checking for a "name" key and a "firstName" key then both the tyler and joe values would be mapped to the key and in the case of the object with a "userName" key a default value would be mapped to the key.

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/sinda/easy-check - it works both server and client side

Comment: easy check seems to work great with values but my issue has more to do with I'm not sure what key to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module aldeed:simple-schema

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema

This is a great module for Schema validation of Javascript data. The default use of this is to attach the schema to a mongo collection in meteor to make sure that the data you are saving is formatted correctly.

If you are saving this data then this could work for you that way. Otherwise you can also just create the schema and ask it to verify an object.

Using this method you can both clean and validate data. That is you can attempt to clean the data first with custom handlers that try to find and map fields, and then validate it to your schema and fail the insert if it does not conform.